# My page is not reflecting any css styling changings I make

Tags: css, django

My page is not loading css correctly.

I am learning django framework for building websites. I am trying to style my page with css. I have gone through the tutorial for managing static files in django. I have done every step mentioned. I am trying to display a jumbtron with a purple background and white text. The code is below. Only the text changes to white but background remains the same. I have had this problem for days. I have searched on the internet but didn't find any answer
[I took a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1IFC.png)

```
{% block styles %}
  <style>
      .jumbotron{
         background: purple;
         color: white;
      }

  </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Dummy content for testing</h1> 
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you show us the master page, it will help a lot.

Comment: Have you tryed to press `F5` in order to refresh the page ?

Comment: You need to go into inspect element and see where the background color is coming from. This will tell you whether another style is overwriting the purple style or if the purple style is never seen by the element. Don't know about your browser, but in Chrome it's right-click and then you choose Inspect. You can also look at the HTML source in your browser and see if the style element is even there.

Answer (score 0):

Its just the cache problem.
Just follow these instructions:-

> Press Ctrl+a then Ctrl+C then delete your all code of file and save the file.

Now just refresh your page.

> After refresh press Ctrl+z and save the file

Now again refresh the page and see the results.

It Works...

Comment: I haven't tested the code yet. I just edited the code and typed ```python3 manage.py runserver``` that's all. I have had this problem before when I started working with django but I ignored because I thought It was a minor issue.

Comment: Did you delete your browser's cache?

Comment: if not then try it first.

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be 
 background-color: purple;

Instead of background: purple;

Comment: I have tried that too. It's just one and the same thing